# How to group parameter values in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I currently have a few parameters set up in my SSRS report, but one is kinda giving me a bit of a headache.

I currently have a parameter called `PARAM_ONE` which is populated by a Dataset that I have. The value is populated the Id field of my Dataset and the label is the TextValue field of my Dataset.

I have another parameter called `PARAM_TWO` which is populated by a Dataset that is filtered based off of what is selected from `PARAM_ONE`. Again the Parameter value is populated by the Id field of this Dataset and the label is the TextValue.

My issue is that this Parameter shows duplicate fields because of the way that the data is set up. There are multiple values that go to the corresponding data I am trying to display. I would like to set it up to group all of my `PARAM_TWO` data that way duplicates are not showing, but I still need that first dataset relationship to map the data.

I hope this makes sense, and someone can help. If I am not making sense and need to clear anything up I would be more than happy to, just let me know.

Comment: Is it possible to use "Select distinct" in your datasets?

Comment: What you said actually gave me an idea and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: If you can't make them distinct, you would usually create a second dataset just for the parameter selection.

Comment: @HannoverFist - I was unable to make this work. Since you cannot take a dataset of a dataset unless if the primary is a shared dataset. If you try and do that, then your shared dataset cannot be filter by a report parameter (this is just to the best of my knowledge and i would be interested in seeing a working instance of it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out the solution to my issue thanks to the help of @user3340627.

In my dataset I created a query that looked something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id, TextValue FROM MyTable
WHERE SecondId = @PARAM_One
```

This created a parameter in the `Parameters` tab called `@PARAM_ONE`. I was then able to map my report parameter to the query parameter and run it with no issues.